# Exception Error in Destructor

Tags: c++, exception, destructor

I know this is very basic but somehow working on different technologies I have mashed up my C++ concepts

I have created a simple program but it is giving exception when the destructor is called.

Below is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
  public:

    Employee(char *name){
      cout<<"Employee::ctor\n";
      myName_p = new char(sizeof(strlen(name)));
      myName_p = name;
    }

    void disp(){cout<<myName_p;}

    ~Employee()
    {
      cout<<"Employee:dtor\n\n";
      delete myName_p;
    }

  private:
    char *myName_p;
};


int main()
{
    Employee emp("check");
    emp.disp();
    return(0);
}
```

Requesting all to clear this basic concept. As per my understanding we can't use delete[] because we are not using new[] in this case. Though I have tried using delete[] , but still it was giving error

Comment: I'd like a new "close vote" reason: "C++ code doesn't use `std::string`"

Comment: The last two lines of your constructor would be hard-pressed to leak memory faster. This isn't Java. And `sizeof(strlen(name))` is the size of a `size_t`, *not* the size of the block of memory needed for the parameter. Consider trying it [like this](http://ideone.com/Sig1vx)

Comment: You need [] to create the array. Otherwise you are creating a single char!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
myName_p = new char(sizeof(strlen(name)));
myName_p = name;
```

to

```
myName_p = strdup(name);
```

and `#include <cstring>`. This creates new space and copies the parameter string. In this way, you'll have to call `free` instead of `delete` in your destructor.

Otherwise, after the second assignment, you have assigned the string literal `"check"` to `myName_p`, and the newly created space is discarded. Then your destructor tries to delete `"check"` rather than the allocated space, which results in crash.

Also, it is better practice to use `std::string` rather than old `char*` strings:

```
class Employee
{
public:
  Employee(char *name): myName_p(name) {
    cout<<"Employee::ctor\n";
  }

  void disp(){ cout << myName_p; }

private:
  std::string myName_p;
};
```

The `string` class will manage memory for you.

Comment: Going with this as an answer as this is a solution to the specific query and Yang was early to answer. Though Mats explanation is complete

Comment: Note that using `strdup`, you should call  `free` rather than `delete` in the destructor.

Answer (score 7):

You REALLY should use `std::string` here.

It is so much easier, especially for a beginner. The list of errors is:

1. you are calculating the wrong size of the `name`, it should be `strlen(name)+1`, not using `sizeof` anything.
2. You also should use `new char[strlen(name)+1]`.
3. You are copying the data from the string supplied as the argument to the constructor, use `strcpy` rather than `name_p = name` - the latter leaks the memory you just allocated, and then you have a pointer to a `const char *` which you should not delete.
4. If you fix the allocation so that it is correct, you should then use `delete [] name_p;`.

However, it you instead use `std::string`, all of the above problems go away completely, you can just do:

```
Employee(char *name) name_p(name) { ... }
```

and get rid of all the problematic `new`, `delete` and  copying. Of course, `name_p` is probably no longer a suitable name for the variable, but you get the idea.

Comment: +1 and beyond that, `const std::string&` for the parameter (or at the very least `const char *`).

Comment: +1, you've addressed everything.  Also `name_p` was never a suitable name :)